# Background image on iPhone 11 simulator is not appropriate size

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm using Xamarin.Forms 4.6.0 and I followed instructions to put images for now on into Assets.xcassets

Its working fine on iPhone 8+ and iPhone8, but when I tried on iPhone 11 Im getting [image: this background]
On my Android mobile everything is ok.

Sizes in my asset that Im using for this background are:

- 1@ - 375x667
- 2@ - 750 x 1334
- 3@ - 1242 x 2208

I found that iPhone 11 screen size is 1792 x 828? If so, where I need to put that resolution? I already occupied 1@,2@ and 3@ in my asset file.

Comment: Can you please share us the code about the image? And what actual result you want? Can you show me a screenshot in iPhone8 too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(YourPage), typeof(CustomPage))]

namespace Your.NameSpace.Project.iOS
{
    public class CustomPage : PageRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(false);

            UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(this.View.Frame.Size);
            UIImage i = UIImage.FromFile("FileImageBackground.png");
            i = i.Scale(this.View.Frame.Size);

            this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(i);

        }
    }
}
```

If your whole project uses background image replace `YourPage` against `Page`

Comment: And how Im consuming this renderer? Im not sure that I understand your code, where I need to put this?

Comment: Just extend https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.contentpage?view=xamarin-forms and named it `YourPage` like @Wilson said, and user YourPage as default page class